# DataTable does not support schema inference from Xml.?

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PHP_Adapter>
  <Adapter>
    <ID>11</ID>
    <Provider>22</Provider>
    <Connectstring>33</Connectstring>
  </Adapter>
</PHP_Adapter>
```

This my Xml file what wrong?

```
    bool CheckAdapterExist(string aid)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.ReadXml(axml);
        MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString());

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try using a **Dataset** rather

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(@"d:\test.xml");
MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ID"].ToString());
```

Found at

[DataTable.ReadXml(filename) throws an error. Why?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataset/thread/1b8c331e-55b7-4cf4-a8ec-c0b24e2a7b3e)

Comment: I think that the question was related to a table, not a dataset. Also, the right way is to add the schema to the custom table.

Comment: @fcm: I believe  @adriaan implied that using a `DataSet` rather than a `DataTable` is one way to get the result the OP was seeking..

Comment: this is real answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20367684/1704458

Answer (score 43):

If you're reading an `XML` file from `DataTable.WriteXml`, make sure you include an `XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema`.

Example:

```
Table.WriteXml(DataFilePath, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

Comment: You would think it should write the schema by default if the ReadXml requires it!!! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Mark! This should be marked as the actual answer. The DataTable does not know the schema unless it is included with the original export. Another way to get around this problem is to create the schema manually when creating the DataTable object, and then read in the data from XML.

Answer (score 9):

This works

```
        string XML = @"
          <MyTable>
            <MyRecord>
              <Col_1>test</Col_1>
              <Col_2>1234</Col_2>
            </MyRecord>
            <MyRecord>
              <Col_1>Record 2</Col_1>
              <Col_2>2</Col_2>
            </MyRecord>
          </MyTable>
        ";
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        DS.ReadXml(new StringReader(XML));

        DataTable DT=DS.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this, this will work :

```
System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader =
                new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(@"C:\Users\Mayank\Documents\Projects\XMLTEST\XMLTEST\XMLFile1.xml");
            DataSet newTable = new DataSet();
            newTable.ReadXml(reader);
            DataTable _dt=newTable.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are the one writing the table, you can solve this problem by writing the schema at the same time as the table. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135456.aspx

Comment: You might want to include an example in case that link ever changes.