# Strange behaviour with ReadXml() method

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I am trying to read an XML file and store it in a datatable by using the following syntax:

```
dtServerNames.ReadXml("ServerPaths.xml");

Could not find file 'c:\documents and settings\590000\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EasyDeployer\EasyDeployer\bin\Debug\ServerPaths.xml'
```

The file was placed in root directory of application i.e in the following path:

```
c:\documents and settings\590000\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EasyDeployer\EasyDeployer
```

but, it is looking for the file in bin foler. Even if i give the full path, it is saying file not exists.

The following is the XML file i am referring to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ServerList>
  <ServerName>
    Dev Server 1
  </ServerName>
  <ServerPath>
    C:\Avinash\Dev1
  </ServerPath>
  <ServerName>
    Dev Server 1
  </ServerName>
  <ServerPath>
    C:\Avinash\Dev2
  </ServerPath>
</ServerList>
```

I have checked Properly where the file is stored. So, i was not able to find why this is happening..

Any ideas why its happening and what are the changes that i can make to make this work?

I am giving the full path like this:

```
dtServerNames.Read(" c:\\documents and settings\\590000\\my documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\EasyDeployer\\EasyDeployer");
```

Comment: Can you show how you access its full path? If you enter the full path, and it still creates an error, then there must be something else wrong.

Comment: c:\\documents and settings\\590000\\my documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\EasyDeployer\\EasyDeployer

Comment: @Avinash It's not a full path, add `\bin\Debug` to it. Or better, place your xml file there and keep your ReadXml line like you provided in your question.

Comment: why not try this  Applicaton.StartupPath+"\\ServerPaths.xml"

Comment: After adding \bin\Debug , i was getting error like:DataTable does not support schema inference from Xml.

Comment: @Avinash Then it means ReadXml had found the file but cannot load it. Are you sure it's a proper XML?

Comment: I have added that XML file , please tell me if it is not Proper

Comment: For your second error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935522/datatable-does-not-support-schema-inference-from-xml

Comment: Ok..Using DataSet Solved My problem to little extent..i was getting new Error while binding to Listbox

Answer (score 1):

If you wants to read file like this tha you must need to put your file in bin folder only other wise you cannot able to read it like this.

If you want to put file somewhere else than bin folder you need to give full path of that folder.

if giving full path than just do this

```
System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader =
  new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(@"C:\Projects\projectname\XMLFile1.xml");
```

Comment: The Problem is even if am giving the full path , it still says file not found!

Comment: @Avinash Then update your question with that exact line containing the full path and the error it gives you.