# Shortest way to save DataTable to Textfile

Tags: c#, datatable, streamwriter

I just found a few answers for this, but found them all horribly long with lots of iterations, so I came up with my own solution:

1. Convert table to string:

   ```
   string myTableAsString = 
       String.Join(Environment.NewLine, myDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().
           Select(r => r.ItemArray).ToArray().
               Select(x => String.Join("\t", x.Cast<string>())));
   ```
2. Then simply save string to text file, for example:

   ```
   StreamWriter myFile = new StreamWriter("fileName.txt");
   myFile.WriteLine(myFile);
   myFile.Close();
   ```

Is there a shorter / better way?

Comment: How much shorter do you want it?

Comment: Oneliner for saving to a file [`File.WriteAllText(location, content);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). There is also the predefined DataTable method [WriteXml(location)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hyx9hb4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that saves the content of the data table to a file.

Comment: If you have working code it does not belong on this site. This site is for fixing broken code.

Comment: If you can work with xml then you might be interested in adding the `DataTable` to `DataSet` and calling `WriteXml` on it.

Comment: I just was wondering if I am not just re-inventing the wheel. If there is a very simple and short way that I just couldn't find out there, I'd appreciate if someone can let me know. The important part is about converting the table into a string, but thanks for the tip to write to a file in a single line, I didn't know it.

Comment: It's easy to read, so I would imagine if it fits your needs and performance constraints, then there's no reason to over-engineer it.

Comment: @rageit Can you provide an example?

Comment: `var dataSet = new DataSet(); 
dataSet.Add(new DataTable()); 
dataSet.WriteXml("filename.xml");`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have your `DataTable` named as myDataTable, you can add it to `DataSet` as:

```
var dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.AddTable(myDataTable);

// Write dataset to xml file or stream
dataSet.WriteXml("filename.xml");
```

And you can also read from xml file or stream:

```
dataSet.ReadXml("filename.xml");
```

Comment: Why do you need to create the DataSet? Can't you just do `myDataTable.WriteXml("filename.xml")` as someone else suggested?

Comment: For some reason I was thinking about multiple tables. If you need just one table to be written then certainly you can go with `DataTable.WriteXml`.

Comment: FYI: In .NET Framework 4.6.2, there is no method on `System.Data.DataSet` named `AddTable`  I used the `Add` method on `DataSet.Tables`.  See [.NET Framework 4.6.2 Documentation for DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=netframework-4.6.2) and [.NET Framework 4.6.2 Documentation for DataTableCollection.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatablecollection.add?view=netframework-4.6.2)

Answer (score 2):

@Leonardo sorry but i can 't comment so i post.

Sometimes you can ask the dataset and then work with it. Like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
    {
        myStreamWriter.Write((string)item + "\t");
    }
    myStreamWriter.WriteLine();
}
```

That 's another way but i don 't know which 'll give you a better metric.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider XML as text you can do: `myDatatable.WriteXml("mydata.xml")` and `myDatatable.ReadXml("mydata.xml")`

Comment: Yes, this looks much simpler too.

Answer (score 2):

You get an error unless you save it with the schema:

```
myDataTable.WriteXml("myXmlPath.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
myDatatable.ReadXml("myXmlPath.xml");
```

There is more info on saving/loading with schema here: 
[DataTable does not support schema inference from Xml.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935522/datatable-does-not-support-schema-inference-from-xml)