# Using XML document as DataSource for DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, datatable, datasource

I have a program which gets data from a database and uses that information to create a XML document.
The program works as intended, but there are issues when the program is used during the nightshift, as the database is usually under maintenance, so the program stops working as intended.

What I want to achieve here is, when the program cant connect to the database, to use a XML document (created with the same data as the database), so the program can work properly during the maintenance periods, basically, using a XML document to create another XML

Here is how the program is connected to the database:

```
namespace Cotas.Class
{
    public class CData
    {
        static string S_Connection = "ConnectionString";

        public static BDMINIAPPS.SP_MINIAPPS SPMINIAPPS = new BDMINIAPPS.SP_MINIAPPS(S_Connection);
        public static BDMINIAPPS.D_CGeometricas CCGeometricos = new BDMINIAPPS.D_CGeometricas(S_Connection);
        public static BDMINIAPPS.D_CGParametros CCGParametros = new BDMINIAPPS.D_CGParametros(S_Connection);
    }
}
```

Method

```
private void LoadConfiguration()
        {
            DataTable DTCGeometricas = CData.SPMINIAPPS.SP_GetCGeometricas();

            D_Tolerancia = decimal.Parse(CData.CCGParametros.SelectCGParametros("Tolerancia").Parametro);
            S_Descripcion = CData.CCGParametros.SelectCGParametros("Descripcion").Parametro;
            S_Encoding = CData.CCGParametros.SelectCGParametros("Encoding").Parametro;
            S_PathOrigen = CData.CCGParametros.SelectCGParametros("PathOrigen").Parametro;
            S_PathDestino = CData.CCGParametros.SelectCGParametros("PathDestino").Parametro;
            S_PathProcesados = CData.CCGParametros.SelectCGParametros("PathProcesados").Parametro;
            S_PathErrores = CData.CCGParametros.SelectCGParametros("PathErrores").Parametro;
            S_ArchivoLOGs = CData.CCGParametros.SelectCGParametros("ArchivoLOGs").Parametro;
            S_Operacion = CData.CCGParametros.SelectCGParametros("Operacion").Parametro;

            foreach (DataRow DRCGeometrica in DTCGeometricas.Rows)
                L_CGeometricas.Add(DRCGeometrica["CGeometrica"].ToString());
        }
```

And this is the command I used to export the data from the Database to a XML document

```
SELECT ( SELECT * From CGeometricas
FOR
XML PATH('Row'), ROOT('CGeometricas'),
TYPE),
(SELECT * From CGParametros
FOR
XML PATH('Row'), ROOT('CGParametros'),
TYPE)
FOR XML PATH('') ,
ROOT('Root')
```

Comment: Would you be willing to consider a simpler alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30582982/283895

Comment: Are you using Entity to connect to database?  If so the you would need to fill the Entity classes from the xml file.